# Product of Lorentz transformation with gamma matrices

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-matrices

In my QFT course, we wrote the following things :

$$ S(\Lambda)^{-1} \gamma^\mu S(\Lambda)=\Lambda^{\mu ~ .}_{. ~ \nu} ~ \gamma^\nu $$

So when we ""apply"" a Lorentz boost to gamma matrices, they are transformed with thoose $S(\Lambda)$ matrices.

And then we found that : (*)

$$ S(\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2)^{-1} \gamma^\mu S(\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2)=S(\Lambda_2)^{-1}S(\Lambda_1)^{-1} \gamma^\mu S(\Lambda_1) S(\Lambda_2) $$

And we said that $S(\Lambda_1)S(\Lambda_2)=\lambda(\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2)S(\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2)$

With $\lambda$ a constant.

I agree that if I have a constant between them, the equation (*) will be satisfied, but is it the only possible solution ?

Also, we said that :

$$ S(\Lambda)^{\dagger}=\gamma^0 S(\Lambda)^{-1} \gamma^0 $$

Is it a natural consequences of the rest? How to prove this?